# Returning array of names using regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to write a function that uses a regex to filter an array of names and returns a new array that contains only those individuals with a given last name. The issue is that it will only return one instance. I feel it's likely due to the regEx - can anyone help?

```js
function getSmith(arr) {
  const regex = /Smith$\b/g;
  return arr.filter(name => regex.test(name));
}

console.log(
  getSmith(['John Smith', 'Chris Smith'])
)
```

Comment: It could be like this `return arr.filter(name => /\bSmith$/.test(name));`

Comment: @Thefourthbird It could but I would rather have the regex pattern defined separately.

Comment: See the duplicate for the reason of that behaviour.

Comment: Remove the `g` flag from your expression (see the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-does-a-regexp-with-global-flag-give-wrong-results) for why). Separately, having `\b` after `$` doesn't make any sense, without the `m` flag `$` means "end of input" and so by definition is a word break. You might want a word break in *front* of `Smith` as @Thefourthbird suggested, though (it depends on whether you want `"John Stringsmith"` to match), and I'd use a case-insensitive match. So `const regex = /\bsmith$/i;`.

Comment: `arr.filter(name => name.toLowerCase().includes("smith"));` is likely a simpler filter to understand